# How to get DataGrid into converter

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridcell, imultivalueconverter

I have this converter, it takes: the current DataGridCell, a DataGridCellInfo object and I'm trying to get the DataGrid object in there as well.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="cellStyle" >
        <Setter Property="helpers:SearchBehaviours.IsTextMatchFocused">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedSearchValueConverter}" FallbackValue="False">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}"/>
                    <Binding Source="{x:Static helpers:MyClass.Instance}" Path="CurrentCellMatch" />
                    <Binding ElementName="GenericDataGrid"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Tried just binding the DataGrid as below, however when this is virtualized and you scroll down and the items are recycled it drops the binding and throws an error.

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=GenericDataGrid'. BindingExpression:Path=;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'IsTextMatchFocused' (type 'Boolean')

In the converter below the DataGridCell is cast to a DataGridCellInfo, and I'm basically comparing the two DataGridCellInfo's row and column index to see if they match, if so return true.

In order to do this I need the DataGrid object. I can see 3 possible solutions: 
1. Maybe I can just compare the two DataGridCellInfo objects to see if they are the same, without having to use a DataGrid object. (I have tried this but it always returns false) 
2. Get the actual DataGrid from one of the DataGridCellInfo objects as it is a parent. (Don't know how to do this). 
3. Get the binding working in a different way.

Obviously this converter will be run for multiple cells whenever one of the bindings change so I would like it to be as efficient as possible.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        if (values[0] == null || values[1] == null || values[2] == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        DataGridCellInfo currentCellInfoMatch = (DataGridCellInfo)values[1];
        if (currentCellInfoMatch.Column == null)
            return false;

        DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo((DataGridCell)values[2]);
        if (cellInfo.Column == null)
            return false;

        DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)values[3];

        int cellInfoItemIndex = ((DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cellInfo.Item)).GetIndex();
        int cellInfoColumnIndex = cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex;
        int currentCellInfoMatchItemIndex = ((DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(currentCellInfoMatch.Item)).GetIndex();
        int currentCellInfoMatchColumnIndex = currentCellInfoMatch.Column.DisplayIndex;

        if (cellInfoItemIndex == currentCellInfoMatchItemIndex && cellInfoColumnIndex == currentCellInfoMatchColumnIndex)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SelectedSearchValueConverter error : " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to pass in the DataGrid to the converter, or can you just use the DataGridCell to get the containing DataGrid via the Parent (or some other) property?

Comment: @VP. either of them are fine. If you know of a way to one or the other please post.

Comment: Just added an answer below, give it a peek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do like the given solution of giving it to the converter via a RelativeSource, it can also be done a different way. It is possible to not pass a DataGrid parameter, but instead find it from the DataGridCell once inside the converter via the `Parent` property on the DataGridCell.

To do this, you'll need a parent-finding helper method:

```
private T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    T parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) as T;  
    if (parent != null)
        return parent;
    else
        return FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

You may chose to put this code in a reusable spot, or even make it an extension method, but here is how you call it once within the converter:

```
DataGrid parentDataGrid = FindParent<DataGrid>(dataGridCell);
```

Comment: Sorry this failed on every cell with the following: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
SelectedSearchValueConverter error : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you could use a `RelativeSource Binding` to achieve your requirement. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="cellStyle" >
    <Setter Property="helpers:SearchBehaviours.IsTextMatchFocused">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedSearchValueConverter}" FallbackValue="False">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}"/>
                <Binding Source="{x:Static helpers:MyClass.Instance}" Path="CurrentCellMatch" />
<!-- ----> -->  <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks however I am still getting the error in the comment below this one. I think the reason being the disconnected (recycled) item in virtualized DataGrid.

Comment: System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'IsTextMatchFocused' (type 'Boolean')